# jasper reports studio - how to add header information

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm building my first report with Jasper Studio. It's a basic Pick List for picking items.

I have 2 tables - Pick & Pick Item - very common master/detail.

I want to add information from the pick table to the header, like pick number, start date etc. Then in the detail section I want to add the detail rows, like sku, quantity etc.

How do I do it? Do I need to create a subreport for the detail? that seems complicated for a simple requirement...is there an easier way (maybe group by)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you create a Domain in which you add your tables, join your header and detail tables and add their required output fields to the display (see the Display tab on the far right in Domain Designer).

Then you create an Ad Hoc View based on that domain in which you select the fields from the header and detail. In this case, it sounds like you would put the header fields at the group level, but that wouldn't strictly be necessary - depends on how you want it to display.

When you save the Ad Hoc View, there is an option to "save and create report" or something like that. Choose that and then go to the report for any additional formatting.

Like a lot of software, Jasper has more than one way to get it done, but as a beginner that's the standard approach you should follow.

Comment: I can't find something called Domain Designer - is it a different version? I'm using latest studio designer - do you mean the outline view where the fields are listed?

Comment: Ah never mind I figured it out, I just added the fields into the header section and it seems to have worked even though they're not grouped.

Comment: Sorry - I think I was answering something different. I use the Jaspersoft web report writer, which I think is different than the studio designer.

Comment: No worries, I think it's similar anyway. Thanks.